# Apache Beam - Write BigQuery TableRow to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to read data from BigQuery (using TableRow) and write the output to Cassandra. How to do that?

Here's what I've tried. This works:

```
/* Read BQ */
PCollection<CxCpmMapProfile> data =  p.apply(BigQueryIO.read(new SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, CxCpmMapProfile>() {
    public CxCpmMapProfile apply(SchemaAndRecord record) {
        GenericRecord r = record.getRecord();
        return new CxCpmMapProfile((String) r.get("channel_no").toString(), (String) r.get("channel_name").toString());
    }
}).fromQuery("SELECT channel_no, channel_name FROM `dataset_name.table_name`").usingStandardSql().withoutValidation());

/* Write to Cassandra */
data.apply(CassandraIO.<CxCpmMapProfile>write()
    .withHosts(Arrays.asList("<IP addr1>", "<IP addr2>"))
    .withPort(9042)
    .withUsername("cassandra_user").withPassword("cassandra_password").withKeyspace("cassandra_keyspace")
    .withEntity(CxCpmMapProfile.class));
```

But when I changed **Read BQ** part using TableRow like this:

```
/* Read from BQ using readTableRow */
PCollection<TableRow> data = p.apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
    .fromQuery("SELECT channel_no, channel_name FROM `dataset_name.table_name`")
    .usingStandardSql().withoutValidation());
```

In **Write to Cassandra** I got the following error

`The method apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<TableRow>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<TableRow> is not applicable for the arguments (CassandraIO.Write<CxCpmMacProfile>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the input PCollection containing `TableRow` elements, while the CassandraIO read is expecting `CxCpmMacProfile` elements. You need to read the elements from BigQuery as `CxCpmMacProfile` elements. The [BigQueryIO documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.23.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html) has an example of reading rows from a table and parsing them into a custom type, done through the [`read(SerializableFunction)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.23.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#read-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-) method.

Comment: thanks, so it seems that the only option in this case would be a custom type, not TableRow